# Are questions about whether or not a complicated mathematical problem of something in physics has been solved suitable here?

Tags: support

I asked the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616734/has-it-been-researched-whether-there-exists-a-shape-that-can-undergo-zero-resist on Physics Stack Exchange. It was not well received there. My question is

> Is it suitable to ask whether a specific complex mathematical problem I created whose answer would be useful for physics has been independently created and solved or its answer can be easily obtained from already existing math research results, if I clearly define what the mathematical problem is?

For example, one question I might ask whether or not has been solved might be something like my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616734/has-it-been-researched-whether-there-exists-a-shape-that-can-undergo-zero-resist. Another such question might be something like the question of whether it's mathematically possible to have a set of mirrors and a screen such that sets of parallel light rays focus at an exact point on the screen which I would probably make clearer if I actually asked the question. Another such question might be my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401303/is-it-possible-to-have-a-state-of-the-universe-with-no-solution-to-what-state-it.

If the answer to this question is no, I might ask another question of whether Mathematics Stack Exchange should change to work that way.

Comment: I doubt that the question would be very well received here.  It really appears to be a physics question, not a mathematics question.  The fact that it was considered off-topic on [physics.se] does not automatically imply that it would be considered on-topic somewhere else on the SE network.

Comment: How much mathematics do you know?  If you have a mathematics problem, regardless of what the original context was, it can almost surely be posed as a Question at Math.SE.  The difficulty for you, especially if you haven't yet formulated the math problem, is to learn enough mathematics to be able to ask a good Question.  My advice, if you are serious about undertaking this study, is to drop back to a level on which you feel grounded enough to be able to verify when a Question you pose is properly solved.

Comment: @hardmath I don't want to invest a lot of time in that actually. I feel like it is not the most useful thing to do at all.

Comment: I think the question was closed on physics S.E. because it wasn't focused enough. I mean no ill intent by stating this a 2nd time (it's already a comment by someone else), I'm just suggesting that this is the main reason it has remained closed on physics S.E. If you rewrote your question with up to date knowledge (you now know that any fluid without viscosity will produce no resistance), and only asked one question in the post, then you could probably get an answer.

Comment: *"I don't want to invest a lot of time in that actually. I feel like it is not the most useful thing to do at all."* Don't expect people on Math.SE or anywhere else to have more interest in your own question than you do. If you feel it's useless, why would we bother to answer?